# AS3: returning to a scene in the main timeline from an embedded moveclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So basically, I have a movieclip with the name homeButton, embedded in another movieclip named overlay. This overlay is placed on every scene within the movie. What I want to happen, is when the homeButton is clicked from any of the scenes, to return to the scene "floorSelect"

Within the overlay symbol, I have the actionscript:

```
homeButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, homeButtonClicked);

function homeButtonClicked(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    parent.gotoAndPlay(1, "floorSelect");
}
```

I'm guessing my error is in the gotoAndPlay, I have tried:

```
root.gotoAndPlay(1, "floorSelect");
parent.parent.gotoAndPlay(1, "floorSelect");
```

thanks in advance,
J

Comment: I am also getting the error: `Symbol 'overlay', Layer 'as', Frame 1, Line 21 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method gotoAndPlay through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try these?

```
MovieClip(root).gotoAndPlay(1,'floorSelect');
// or
MovieClip(parent).gotoAndPlay(1,'floorSelect');
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thank you so much. One quick question, is there anyway to stop it going to the next scene if you press the homeButton from the floorSelect scene? OR disable the button in that particular scene.

Comment: Don't worry, I've figured it out. I just used 'gotoAndStop()' to make sure it doesn't carry on. Thanks again for your help @inhan

Comment: No problem. Make sure that gotoAndPlay/Stop is called from the right scope.